# How to schedule weekday-aware jobs in celery

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celerybeat

Is it possible to configure a sophisticated schedule with celery beat? For example, something like this:

On Monday-Friday, do job A with parameters (x1, y1), then do job B
On Saturday, Sunday, do job A with parameters (x2, y2), don't do job B

I know I can implement a high frequency "tick" task that will check for this schedule, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if something for this already exists.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Sure, use a [crontab schedule](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules) for your tasks.

```
from celery.schedules import crontab

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    # Executes every weekday morning at 7:30 A.M
    'weekdays': {
        'task': 'tasks.A',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=7, minute=30, day_of_week='1-5'),
        'args': (x1, y1),
    },
    # Executes saturday at 4:00 A.M
    'saturday': {
        'task': 'tasks.B',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=4, minute=0, day_of_week='sat'),
        'args': (x1, y1),
    },
    # Executes sunday morning at 2:15 A.M
    'sunday': {
        'task': 'tasks.A',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=2, minute=15, day_of_week='sun'),
        'args': (x2, y2),
    },
}
```

Comment: Is that tied to the OS crontab, or internal to celerybeat?

Comment: @Goro: It's a Celery-provided class.